# Is it safe to enable Clean Master service?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, root-access, services

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

The above are capture of Clean Master that asks for service enable. Is it safe enough to turn the service ON?

Comment: Fun Fact: My Samsung Galaxy S3 came with Clean Master pre-installed back in the day. Didn't take me long to figure out it didn't do anything and not long after that promptly removed only to learn later it wasn't just bloat, but questionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer of that app, Cheetah Mobile, has been accused of committing ad-frauds. XDA has it covered in detail [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/cheetah-mobile-ad-fraud-android-apps/). I would suggest to refrain from using any product from such developer. If you can remove such an app or at least disable it, than consider it.

Comment: And technically speaking, such apps do nothing special that can't be done manually, except using device resources in background continuously and showing useless notifications and activities.

Comment: Thank you for that your info. I mmediately remove it after I read your link.

Comment: Thanks for your warnings against Cheetah. History catches up with them based on a new report out about Cheetah, and Google Play actions against them. See this: [https://www.xda-developers.com/google-bans-600-apps-play-store/](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-bans-600-apps-play-store/).